# What OpenGL version should I pick for my needs?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering

I am using the [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) library to create a display and rendering on the display is done by OpenGL.
I barely know about OpenGL, I've learned to use some of the basic methods in version 1.1, but in a question I have asked before I was told it's not recommended to use this versions of OpenGL(Since 1.1 is from 1997). So my main question was what OpenGL version should  I pick and learn? I am developing a 2d game and I want the game to work on almost every computer. I need to know what's a version that isn't too old and is working good.

I was exploring the internet and still haven't found an answer..
If you could provide some resources that would be nice.

Comment: Are you interested in Desktop or Mobile OpenGL?

Comment: @BorisIvanov Desktop development, maybe Mobile OpenGL in the future.

Comment: Please consider looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044882/difference-between-opengl-3-x-and-4-x and http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Language_bindings#Java
Personally I would go for near latest version.

Comment: for mobile Opengl ES 2.1. for desktop opengl 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

The reason people say "don't use the old OpenGL versions" is because the hole fixed-function pipeline is deprecated, shouldn't be used and it is so darn slow.

Here is a great Google Docs Spreadsheet containing most OpenGL functions and whether or not they are deprecated, etc.

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At5QLa2ZAYZBdHFLbEtvOHF5S1NobWJFbmpDUHZSWWc#gid=0

*Be aware that the spreadsheet is custom made by the people who use OpenGL and not created by the people who make and develop OpenGL.*

> So my main question was what OpenGL version should I pick and learn? I am developing a 2d game and I want the game to work on almost every computer. I need to know what's a version that isn't too old and is working good.

I would say use something like version 3.x or above. Then probably most computers are able to run your program, since version 3.0 was released in 2008.

By using newer versions of OpenGL, you will then be able to use a lot of things like VBOs, VAOs, FBOs, Shaders and much more. Also by not using the fixed-function pipeline functions like `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` will also give you a huge boost in frames.

Though if you want to support ALL computers, even people which have ancient computers. Then I would say the best way to do so, would be to implement multiple ways of doing different things. When you're going to render something if the computer supports VAOs use them, if it doesn't support them, then don't use them, etc.

### Extra

#### OpenGL Release Dates

Here are the release dates for the different OpenGL versions.

- 1.1 – March 4, 1997
- 1.2 – March 16, 1998
- 1.2.1 – October 14, 1998
- 1.3 – August 14, 2001
- 1.4 – July 24, 2002
- 1.5 – July 29, 2003
- 2.0 – September 7, 2004
- 2.1 – July 2, 2006
- 3.0 – August 11, 2008
- 3.1 – March 24, 2009
- 3.2 – August 3, 2009
- 3.3 – March 11, 2010
- 4.0 – March 11, 2010
- 4.1 – July 26, 2010
- 4.2 – August 8, 2011
- 4.3 – August 6, 2012
- 4.4 – July 22, 2013